Windows 11 supporting of EAP against Freeradius 3 using EAP-TLS
I am working on an Access Point that supports 802.1X function, and is having issue with Windows 11 23H2 using Intel AX201.  The issue doesn't seem to happen on iPhone.
The customer just complained that the AP's WPA Enterprise function failed when they use their certificate against Freeradius 3.2.5.  When I ask them to provide the certificate/key to be tested on my side, but they only provide the client's Certificate/Key pair in PKCS (.p12) format.  Since they aren't willing to provide anything else, so I just go ahead with it, since logically it should work since both are signed by the same CA.
I first setup the Freeradius 3.2.5 to support EAP TLS with tls_max_version = tls1.2.  The TLS version used during handshake is TLS 1.3, and Access reject with SSL_read() error "access denied" is received from Windows 11.  I change back to my certificate pair (One for Server, and another one for Client, and both signed by the same CA), and TLS 1.2 version is used instead, and everything works fine including the subsequent EAPOL (4-way handshake)
Since TLS 1.3 is used, so I try my luck by enabling TLS 1.3 on Freeradius 3 server by modifying tls_max_version to tls1.3.  Strange enough, it works, and Access Accept is sent with MS-MPPE-Send-Key and MS-MPPE-Recv-Key contained.
A stranger thing happen, after the Access Accept is sent, the AP initiates the first step of EAPOL by sending Step 1 of handshake, but no response from Windows 11 detected.
Since this issue doesn't happen with iPhone, nor Linux WPA supplicant, (not sure about Android), I assume this only happens on Windows.  So my question is followed:

Does Windows 11 reject the same certificate/key used between both server and client?  or it only use TLS 1.3 when such scenario happens?

If Access Accept is sent, is there anyway to determine if Windows 11 has received the MS-MPPE-Send-Key and MS-MPPE-Recv-Key, and generate Master Session Key to be used for subsequent EAPOL?

Is there anyway to support such scenario by changing Freeradius configuration?

According to this website,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/extensible-authentication-protocol/windows-11-changes


Windows 11 has claimed support of TLS 1.3 in its EAP-TLS, and anything wrong should be Radius Server incorrectly advertise TLS 1.3 support.  Since Freeradius Server supports TLS 1.3 as well, then what might be the problem that causes this issue.
Thank you all in advance for read this long post
